# What is this design trend/style called

Tags: logo, style-identification, style

I'm having a hard time figuring out what this design trend/style is called.

I have a logo given to me by a client. I've seen this style of logo many times on the web. However, I do not know the design style name. I'd like to search up more logos and web design examples that match this style.
[image]

Comment: Looks like vintage style logo.

Comment: Hello Brent and welcome to GraphicDesign! Please edit your question to fit our [style identification guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2931/23061) or else your question may be closed. As is, it's not clear which style of this logo you're interested in (there are several styles used)

Answer (score 4):

There's 3 ways you can call this style:

*Vintage logo*

or

*Badge logo*

or

*Hipster logo.*

The way you'll decide to call it probably depends on why you need that term.

To a client, you might want to use "vintage" but if you're looking for tutorials or ideas online, you will find a lot of results too using the word "hipster" and "badge logo"!

Comment: One could also call it *flat*, *carnival style*, or other names. As such, I think the question is too broad